# How can I make MVC3 Editor Form for Object with collection member type?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Consider the following data classes:

```
class TopLevel
{
    public TopLevel()
    {
        collection = new Item[3];
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Item[] collection { get; set; }
}

class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

I made an Editor Template for Item:

```
   <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Value)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Value)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Value)
    </div>
```

My create csthml for TopLevel looks like this:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.LabelFor( m => m.Name )
    @Html.EditorFor( m => m.Name )
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor( m => m.Name )

    for (int i = 0; i < Model.Collection.Count(); i++)
    {
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Collection[i])
    }

    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
}
```

But in my controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create( TopLevel tl )
{
    //tl.Collection contains three null Items.
}
```

The Item's that make up Collection in my TopLevel class do not get created.  Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this article](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/) for a solution. The magic is contained in the `using(Html.BeginCollectionItem("..."))` block.

Comment: Thanks.  I also found that things worked if I made the Collection field a List<Item>() instead of an array.